# What does Dutch mean in Predator when he said that fighting armed people made Predator a “poor sport?”

Tags: dialogue, predator

In the movie *Predator* (1987), near the end, after they try to trap the Predator in that net, and it shoots its way out, a lot of them die.

One guy is badly injured, so Dutch (Arnold Schwarzenegger) and that girl help him walk. When the woman tries to pick up a gun, Dutch tells her not to because the Predator didn’t kill her before because she was unarmed, then Dutch calls the Predator a “no sport.”

How is only fighting armed people being a poor sport? Did Arnold ad lib this line and fail badly?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It means exactly the opposite of your take on it. I think Arnold said "No Sport" to indicate that if she was unarmed, she would be too easy to kill; not sporting. If she was armed by picking up the gun, the Predator would consider her to be true sport, in a fairer fight.

Here's a [sound clip](http://www.hark.com/clips/rszljdktfc-not-sporting) of a quote from *Blade Runner* that conveys the same message more clearly: 
Roy Batty: *"Not very sporting to fire on an unarmed opponent."*

Answer (score 6):

Old question, but the [exact quote from Dutch in the film is this](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093773/quotes/qt0315356) as confirmed on IMDB:

> “Leave it. He didn’t kill you because you weren’t armed. No sport.”

Reading that as text in a proper sentence, it is clear that the “No sport.” is in the context of Anna (Elpidia Carrillo) being considered not worthy of killing since she was “no sport” since she wasn’t armed.

To the Predator, there is no fun (aka: no sport) in killing an unarmed opponent.

The problem is between the fast talking and Arnold Schwarzenegger’s thick accent, it’s a bit difficult to understand that the words are a small two word sentence fragment. It might also even sound like the “No sport.” is a statement criticizing the Predator itself for being a “no sport.” and such.